# create vm xen python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I am able to perform VM operations using xenapi. How do I create a new VM on xenserver in python? I couldn't find any relevant docs regarding create VM. Any help, direct or recommended reading/links would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean writing down a script in `Python` that creates a VM and boot it on top of XEN? I think that you should have a look at the bash xen commands to control and manipulate the hypervisor. For example `xl` (https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/unstable/man/xl.1.html)

Comment: Yes, I meant writing a script in Python. Anyways I've done it now. Thanks.